# How to make a .pgw file for a .png depicting a 2D profile

Tags: georeferencing, png, profile, 2d

My question is more of an inquiry about whether I am trying to do is possible. I would like to reference an image depicting a 2D Georadar profile. I know that world files are usually used for georeferencing but I am curious about whether I could do it for a vertical slice. Now, the pixel dimensions of my picture are 3715x356 and the coordinates are:
top left corner: 0, 8.53
bottom right corner: 628.5, -9.17
Remember these coordinates indicate horizontal distance along the profile and depth in relation to sea level (negative value means below sea level).

Is it possible to create a .pgw file for this image and how would it look like? What is the norm for making one? I tried to make one myself but the .pgw file although recognized, doesn't affect the coordinates of the referenced image. The referenced image I get has the pixel dimensions as length per axis.